# 言っていた Conjugation

Tags: conjugations

I tried to find this answer in other questions in order to not duplicate it, but i couldn't find one answer for that.

So I was trying to make the following sentence

> There's a ramen restaurant in my town. My friend said that there it is delicious, so I want to go there.

People on hellotalk helped to make my sentence more natural, like changing レストラン　for 屋, and the sentence came out like this:

> 僕の街にラーメン屋があります。僕の友達がおいしいと言っていたので、そのラーメン屋に行きたい。

I understood the whole sentence but one part "言っていた" this is supposed to mean that my friend told me something right. I just don't get the whole "verb te form+いた".

Can you help me with that?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/when-is-v%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-the-continuation-of-action-and-when-is-it-the-continuation-of-state?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Probably related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14764/whats-the-difference-between-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-and-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F And, these pages might help: http://www.alc.co.jp/jpn/article/faq/03/58.html ・ http://nihongodaybyday.blogspot.jp/2010/01/vs.html 「他の人（第三者）が言ったことを第二者に伝える場合には、「言って(い)た」を使います。」

Comment: 友達がおいしい
My friend is tasty? Should が really be here?

Comment: You should parse it as 「友達が『おいしい。』と言っていた。」= "My friend said '(It's ) tasty'."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> "verb te form + いた"

～ていた has several meanings/usages, which include:

- A continuous action in the past (Past progressive tense) -- for action verbs

  > - 彼が来たとき、私はテレビを見**ていた**。I **was watching** TV when he came.
  > - そのころ、私はピアノを弾い**ていた**。I **was playing** piano around that time.
- A state in the past -- for verbs that describe changes in state, eg 死ぬ, 知る, 持つ, 結婚する etc.

  > - 彼は死ん**でいた**。 He was dead.
  >     (Not "He was dying." 彼は死んだ would be "He died.")
  > - 彼は車を持っ**ていた**。 He had a car.
  >     (He was in the state of having a car, not in the middle of the action of having a car. 車を持った would indicate the action of having/getting a car.)
  > - 彼女は結婚し**ていた**。 She was married.
  >     (彼女は結婚した would be "She got married.")
- An action that occurred before another action occurred in the past (Something similar to the past perfect tense in English)

  > - 駅に着くと、もう電車は出発し**ていた**。
  >     The train **had** already **left** when I got to the station.
  > - 彼が来たときには、私は宿題を終え**ていた**。
  >     I **had finished** my homework when / by the time he came.
  > - パーティはすでに始まっ**ていた**。
  >     The party **had** already **begun**.

And, in your example:

- In reported speech (especially in conversation) -- When you tell someone what another person has said to you.

  > - 山田さんは、東京に行くと言っ**ていた**よ。(≂ 行くそうだよ。)
  >     Yamada-san said / I heard Yamada-san say that he was going to Tokyo.
  >     (rather than 山田さんは、東京に行くと言ったよ。)
  > - 彼はなんと言っ**ていました**か？ -- 今日は来ないと言っ**ていました**。(≂ 来ないそうです。)
  >     What did he say? -- He said he would not come today.
  >     (rather than 彼はなんと言いましたか？ -- 今日は来ないと言いました。)
  > - ニュースで、大きな地震があったって言っ**てた**よ。
  >     I heard on TV news that there was a big earthquake.

---

> 僕の街にラーメン屋があります。僕の友達がおいしいと言っ**ていた**ので、そのラーメン屋に行きたい。

Here, おいしいと言っ**ていた**ので is more natural than おいしいと言ったので, since it's reported speech. This is like "I heard my friend say..." or "My friend told me..."

I think it'd be even more natural to say it this way:

> 僕の街に**は**ラーメン屋があります。(僕の)友達がおいしいと言っていたので、そのラーメン屋に行きたい**です**。

- Add the topical は. 「僕の街に**は**～～」
- Leave out the second 僕の. It's obvious whose friend you're talking about here.
- Add です at the end, since you used polite あります in the first sentence.
- Alternatively, you could say 行きたいと思っています。 or 行ってみたいです。

Comment: Could you please explain or elaborate on why you used 着く rather than 着いた in your example "駅に着くと、もう電車は出発していた"?

Comment: @G-Cam The conjunctive particle と follows the dictionary form verb, so you say 「着く+と」(when/if ~ arrive), not 「*着いた+と」.  If you used たら (= the hypothetical form of the auxiliary verb た), then you'd say 「着い+たら」.

Comment: Thanks!!! One question, when "quotting" someone speech or thought, what's the difference between と and って ?

Comment: って is more colloquial than と. E.g. 「友達がおいしいと言っていたので・・・」-> more casually/colloquially:「友達がおいしい**って**言っ**てた**から・・・」

Comment: sorry for the continuous trouble, but can you explain me the difference between 見ていた and 見てた? Is it any different or removing the い just makes it little more colloquial?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Yes, 見てた is a colloquial way of saying/pronouncing 見ていた. The い in the subsidiary verb (～て)いる often drops in conversation. Other examples: 見ておく->見とく (dropping "e" sound), 見ていく->見てく(dropping い). You can find more examples here if you're interested: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30996/9831

Answer (score 1):

You could say :

> 僕の友達がおいしいと言ったので、そのラーメン屋に行きたい。

But what you have (in the OP) is a more sophisticated way to put it, which is an abbreviated ( less sophisticated ) way of saying :

> 僕の友達がおいしいと言っていたので、そのラーメン屋に行きたくなった。
>
> (1) Because I had been told X,　　(2) I began to think Y.

2 happened in the past, and 1 happened even before it.

言っていた is a Jp way of expressing this "tense-" relationship.

---

I think French and Spanish have a more established way of expressing this than English does. (The usual sentence pattern is: -- When i got to the station, the train had just left. When i saw him, he was at the bank.)

> When I saw him, he was carrying a red bag.
>
> その人を見た時に、彼は赤いカバンを持っていた。

My seeing him happened in the past, and his having (obtaining, grabbing) 持つ the bag happened even before that, and 
持っていた is a Jp way of expressing this "tense-" relationship.

This [red bag] example is a paraphrase of the following :

> http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/24asupekuto.html
>
> その時、田中さんは赤いかばんを持っていました。
>
> 「持っていた」の例では、その全体が過去のことになっています。この話し手が「田中さんがかばんを持っている」のを見たのが過去のある時で、「田中さんがカバンを持った」のはそれよりも前の時点で
>   す。
>
> （「その時」より前に）持った →　（その時）持っていた

---

(For me, at least) 言っていた, 持っていた feel like [imperfect tense] in French and Spanish. ----- 半過去 in French, 線過去（不完了過去） in Spanish.

半過去： 継続している過去、 終わりがはっきりしていない過去（未完了）、 そのシーンの背景。 過去の進行中の行為。 過去の習慣（何度か行ったこと）。

"My friend had been saying" may be a great way to think about it.

---

I can't find a good page (or any page) on this in English. Is there one?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but i can't really tell the difference between the two conjugations, would it be the difference between "My friend told me" and "My friend had been saying"? I'm not sure :(

Comment: I think that's one good way to think about it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'll wait to see if anyone else have a different approach in this question!

Comment: Hey, thank you for the complement, I understand it, one last thing, if i want to turn another verb into this tenso, let's say [行く] how do i do this? Te form plus いる or ある in the past? or what

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Japanese/Grammar/%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B